# Type for array indices: signed/unsigned integer avantages

Tags: c++, c

In C++, the default size for array indices is size_t which is a 64 bits *unsigned* 64-bits integer on most x86-64 platforms. I am in the process of building my own std::vector class for my library for High Performance Computing (One of the main reason is that I want this class to be able to take ownership of a pointer, something std::vector does not offer). For the type of the array index, I am thinking of either using:

- size_t
- my own index_t that would be a *signed* int or a long signed int depending on my program

The advantages or using a signed integer over an unsigned one are numerous, such as

```
for (index_t i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; ++i)
```

works like it is supposer to (with an unsigned integer, this loop goes crazy when v is of size 0)

```
for (index_t i = v.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
```

works like it is supposed to, and many other avantages. In terms of performance, it even seems to be a little bit better as

```
a + 1 < b + 1
```

can be reduced to a < b with signed integer (overflow is undefined), and not in the case of unsigned integers. The only avantage performance wise seems to be that a /= 2 can be reduced to a shift operation with unsigned integers but not with signed one.

I am wondering why the C++ committee has decided to use an *unsigned* integer for size_t as it seems to introduce a lot of pain and only few  advantages.

Comment: Other than you think, unsigned types work perfectly when doing arithmetic, also when counting down indices. If you think in ranges, this turn out very well, `i < v.size()` would do the trick here. Otherwise, if you want a signed type for such purposes chose `ptrdiff_t` this is the correct type foreseen to code differences. Maybe you find this interesting, it is mainly about C, but here for once the two are much tied together. http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2013/07/15/a-praise-of-size_t-and-other-unsigned-types/. Ah, and also voting to close, because this is primarily opinion based.

Comment: @Gustedt: Thanks for the link which is interesting. I have tried to focus the subject on facts rather than opinions. Some folks helped me to think about using ptrdiff_t which has been useful.

Answer (score 8):

The motivation for using an unsigned type as index or size in
the standard is based on constraints only relevant to 16 bit
machines.  The *natural* type for any integral type in C++ is
`int`, and that's what should probably be used; as you've
noticed, trying to use unsigned types as numerical values in C++
is fraught with problems.  If you're worried about the sizes
being so big that they don't fit into an `int`, `ptrdiff_t`
would be appropriate; this is, after all, the type of the
results of subtraction of pointers or iterators.  (The fact that
`v.size()` has a different type than `v.end() - v.begin()` is
really a design flaw in the standard library.)

Comment: The fact that v.size() and v.end() - v.begin() seems really strange for me too. Thanks for the hint on historical reasons and 16 bits machines.

Comment: I finally decided to use my own type called index_t which will be a signed int. I will mainly use an int or a ptrdiff_t for it. The int will be better when I want to use huge arrays of index_t if I want to go easy on the memory bandwidth, and the ptrdiff_t will be useful when I want very large arrays.

Comment: But using signed types makes sign conversion and sign compare warnings fire every time I use them with standard library containers like `std::vector` (to index or when comparing with `.size()`). Do you just disable these warnings or do you `static_cast` every occurrence? The latter seem very tedious to me.

Comment: Hi Baum. I just use my own vector implementation. The .size() method returns a signed integer which makes everything smooth. If you use std::vector, you are commited to use std::size_t.

Comment: @BaummitAugen It depends.  There's no simple rule, and the fact that `std::vector<>::size` returns an unsigned type is lamentable, because of the issues it creates.  But since I rarely use `std::vector<>::size`, it's not an issue.  The difference between two iterators is a signed type, and ultimately, that gets used more often.

Answer (score 4):

For me, unsigned sizes always make the most sense, since you can't have -32 elements in an array it is very very scary to consider the size/length as a signed quantity all the time.

The corner cases you mention can be coded around, you can e.g. abort the loop before entering it if `v` is empty for the first case (which doesn't look all that common to begin with, iterating over all elements except the last?).

Comment: Looping over all but the last element can be useful in many examples. I am thinking of a bubble sort or going through the elements M(i, i + 1) (the diagonal just above the main one) of a matrix. I understand the "it does convey a message that the integer is nonnegative" thing but most people have used int to go through arrays in C and feel fine with int.

Comment: An index is a numerical value, and unsigned integral types don't behave well as numerical values.  (E.g. `abs(i1 - i2)` does _not_ give the difference between the two indices.)  Ideally, indices would be a range type, but C++ doesn't have ranged types.  And trying to fake it with `unsigned` doesn't help, since it still leaves the upper range uncontrolled.  Unsigned integral types in C++ are designed for a few very specific uses, like bit manipulation or when modulo arithmetic is really wanted.

Comment: @JamesKanze: The problem is that there are two use cases for unsigned types (natural numbers, and rings congruent mod 2^N), and they have different requirements, but rather than using separate types C makes unsigned types which are smaller than `int` as the first, and those which are larger than `int` behave the other.  Adding distinct types for e.g. `unumN_t` and `uwrapN_t`, with the former guaranteeing promotion to a signed type, and the latter guaranteeing that it won't be promoted, could make things much cleaner.